# All RAM consumed while appending in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I have a dataframe (2125, 7) which has fix term deposits information. The problem that i m trying to solve is that i need to have all possible permutations for a given group since i don t know which deposit came first. To overcome this I first created a function to return all the permutations except those which are not possible in term of business. For example, i can have 2 deposits with same account_num but difference account_sequence_num hence the one with the smaller seq num will always come first. My issue is that i m running out of RAM memory and i don t know how to optimize my code to make it through. Here's my code:

```
#df_resultante --> main df with:
#Account_num               int64   16 digits
#Account_sequence_num      int64   2 digits
#Party_id                 object   11 charac
#Stock_inicio            float64
#Participacion_pf        float64
#Tasa                    float64
#party_group              object
```

Since a given deposit can have 2 or more parties then i create a new df clean of duplicates

```
df_resultante_testing=df_resultante[['Account_num', 'Account_sequence_num','party_group']].drop_duplicates().sort_values(['Account_num', 'Account_sequence_num','party_group'], ascending=[True,True, True])
```

Function to return permutations for a given group of people:

```
from itertools import permutations
    def create_combinations(dataframe,grupo):
      an=dataframe[dataframe['party_group']==grupo]['Account_num'].values.tolist()
      s=dataframe[dataframe['party_group']==grupo]['Account_sequence_num'].values.tolist()
      an_s=list(zip(an,s))
    
      comb=list(permutations(an_s))
      comb_clean=[]
      wrong=0
      for elemento in comb:
        e=0
        for pf,sec in elemento:
          e=e+1
          if any([True for pf2,sec2 in elemento[e:] if ((pf2 == pf) and (sec>sec2))]):
            wrong=wrong+1
        if wrong==0:
          comb_clean.append(elemento)
        wrong=0  
      return comb_clean
```

Now this is the part which fails to complete because i run out of memory

```
#grupos has around 1500 elements
grupos= df_resultante['party_group'].unique().tolist()
datos=list()

for g in grupos:
  combinations = create_combinations(df_resultante_testing,g)
  c=1
  for element in combinations :
    for pf,sec in element:
      arr=df_resultante.loc[(df_resultante['Account_num']==pf) & (df_resultante['Account_sequence_num']==sec)].values.tolist()
      for r in arr:
        r.append('Combination ' + str(c)) 
        datos.append(r)      
    c=c+1

print('executed')
```

Ideally once i have 'datos' i would finish with:

```
columnas=['Account_num', 'Account_sequence_num', 'Party_id', 'Stock_inicio','Participacion_pf', 'Tasa','party_group','Combination']
df_new_comb = pd.DataFrame(data=datos,columns=columnas)
```

Comment: Uh, python isn't exactly the most efficient language... For the computer, that is.

Comment: Permutations tend to grow super-exponentially. If you have a large collection and you're generating all the permutations, you won't be able to fit them in memory. Perhaps you can write a generator that produces them as needed rather than creating all the combinations.

Comment: I suspect an [XY problem](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=xy+problem+wikipedia&atb=v142-1&ia=web): why do you need to have all of those permutations in memory at once?  How are you making use of that whole list?  If you're not using the permutations as a mass object of some sort, then your problem is different: "How do I generate these permutations in a useful stream?"  Please back up one level of abstraction and define the problem..

Comment: The underlying problem is that i need to build a $balance for each customer as each deposit occurs because depending on that amount you get rate X% or Y%. i do not know the orders in which the events took place therefore i create all the permutations so then i can track in how many scenarios was rate X% was correctly applied (eg. 6 out 10)